# Why is my quicksort so slow in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I tried to write a quicksort in python (for learning algorithms),but I found it about 10x slower than the native sort.Here's the result:

```
16384 numbers:
native: 5.556 ms
quicksort: 96.412 ms

65536 numbers:
native: 27.190 ms
quicksort: 436.110 ms

262144 numbers:
native: 151.820 ms
quicksort: 1975.943 ms

1048576 numbers:
native: 792.091 ms
quicksort: 9097.085 ms

4194304 numbers:
native: 3979.032 ms
quicksort: 39106.887 ms
```

Does it mean that there's something wrong with my implementation?
Or that's OK because the native sort uses a lot of low-level optimization?

Nevertheless, I feel it unacceptable for sorting of 1 million numbers to take nearly 10s, even though I wrote it just for learning rather than practical application. And my computer is quite fast.
Here's my code:

```
def quicksort(lst):
    quicksortinner(lst,0,len(lst)-1)

def quicksortinner(lst,start,end):
    if start>=end:
        return
    j=partition(lst,start,end)
    quicksortinner(lst,start,j-1)       
    quicksortinner(lst,j+1,end)

def partition(lst,start,end):
    pivotindex=random.randrange(start,end+1)
    swap(lst,pivotindex,end)    
    pivot=lst[end]
    i,j=start,end-1
    while True:
        while lst[i]<=pivot and i<=end-1:
            i+=1
        while lst[j]>=pivot and j>=start:
            j-=1
        if i>=j:
            break
        swap(lst,i,j)

    swap(lst,i,end)
    return i

def swap(lst,a,b):
    if a==b:
        return
    lst[a],lst[b]=lst[b],lst[a]
```

In partition, i scans right and j scans left(the approach from *Algorithms*). Earlier I tried the way where both move right(maybe more common), and there's not much difference.

Comment: maybe could be usefull to read your code

Comment: Without any further information, my money is on "native sort is just ludicrously fast" :-)

Comment: I bet you implemented it in a pythonic way, which makes it slow and also not quicksort. Did you use list comprehensions? That or you implemented the naive version and you're hitting a bad case.

Comment: How are you choosing your pivot? That can make a big difference. If you are generating pseudorandom numbers every time, the time spent in generating these numbers can slow down your algorithm significantly by a constant factor.

Comment: @IVlad  I used list comprehension for generating the data, the time spend for which is not counted.

Comment: The answer is here : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listsort.txt and here : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c (starting around line 965.) TL;DR : Python `list.sort()` is coded in C and highly optimized.

Answer (score 7):

The native sort is written in `C`.  Your quicksort is written in pure `Python`.  A speed difference of **10x** is expected. If you run your code using [PyPy](http://pypy.org/), you should get closer to native speed (PyPy uses a tracing JIT to achieve high performance). Likewise, [Cython](http://cython.org/) would give a nice speed boost as well (Cython is a Python-to-C compiler).

A way to tell if your algorithm is even in the same ballpark is to count the number of comparisons used by both sort algorithms.  In finely tuned code, the comparison costs dominate the running time.  Here's a tool for counting comparisons:

```
   class CountCmps(float):

       def __lt__(self, other):
           global cnt
           cnt += 1
           return float.__lt__(self, other)

>>> from random import random
>>> data = [CountCmps(random()) for i in range(10000)]
>>> cnt = 0
>>> data.sort()
>>> cnt
119883
```

One other factor is your call to *random.randrange()* has many pure Python steps and does more work than you might expect.  It will be a non-trivial component of the total run time.  Because random pivot selection can be slow, consider using a [median-of-three](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Quicksortwithmedianofthreepartitioning.htm) technique for selecting the pivot.

Also, the call to the *swap()* function isn't fast in CPython.  Inlining that code should give you a speed boost.

As you can see, there is a lot more to optimizing Python than just selecting a good algorithm.  Hope this answer gets you further to your goal :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will gain a small speed-up by moving to [iteration instead of recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursion_versus_iteration), although the large part of this is probably due to the native code being very fast.

I illustrate this with reference to [MergeSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). Apologies for not using QuickSort - they work with about the same speed but MergeSort takes a little less time to wrap your head around, and the iterative version is more easy to demonstrate.

Essentially, MergeSort sorts a string by breaking it in half, sorting the two separately (using itself, of course!), and combining the results - sorted lists can be merges in O(n) time so this results in overall O(n log n) performance.

Here is a simple recursive MergeSort algorithm:

```
def mergeSort(theList):
    if len(theList) == 1:
        return theList

    theLength = int(len(theList)/2)

    return mergeSorted( mergeSort(theList[0:theLength]), mergeSort(theList[theLength:]) )

def mergeSorted(theList1,theList2):
    sortedList = []
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0

    while True:
        if counter1 == len(theList1):
            return sortedList + theList2[counter2:]

        if counter2 == len(theList2):
            return sortedList + theList1[counter1:]

        if theList1[counter1] < theList2[counter2]:
            sortedList.append(theList1[counter1])
            counter1 += 1
        else:
            sortedList.append(theList2[counter2])
            counter2 += 1
```

Exactly as you found, this is beaten into the ground by the in-built sorting algorithm:

```
import timeit

setup = """from __main__ import mergeSortList
import random
theList = [random.random() for x in xrange(1000)]"""

timeit.timeit('theSortedList1 = sorted(theList)', setup=setup, number=1000)
#0.33633776246006164

timeit.timeit('theSortedList1 = mergeSort(theList)', setup=setup, number=1000)
#8.415547955717784
```

However, a bit of a time boost can be had by eliminating the recursive function calls in the `mergeSort` function (this also avoids the dangers of hitting recursion limits). This is done by starting at the base elements, and combining them pairwise, a bottom-up approach instead of a top-down approach. For example:

```
def mergeSortIterative(theList):

    theNewList = map(lambda x: [x], theList)
    theLength = 1

    while theLength < len(theList):
        theNewNewList = []

        pairs = zip(theNewList[::2], theNewList[1::2])

        for pair in pairs:
            theNewNewList.append( mergeSorted( pair[0], pair[1] ) )

        if len(pairs) * 2 < len(theNewList):
            theNewNewList.append(theNewList[-1])

        theLength *= 2
        theNewList = theNewNewList

    return theNewNewList[0]
```

Now the growing sorted list elements are stored at each iteration, greatly reducing the memory requirements and eliminating the recursive function calls. Running this gives about a 15% speed boost in my running time - and this was a quickly-thrown-together version

```
setup = """from __main__ import mergeSortIterative
import random
theList = [random.random() for x in xrange(1000)]"""

timeit.timeit('theSortedList1 = mergeSortIterative(theList)', setup=setup, number=1000)
#7.1798827493580575
```

So I'm still no-where near the in-built version, but a little bit better than I was doing before.

A recipe for iterative QuickSort can be found [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-quick-sort/).

Comment: While in other languages that is indeed true, in my experience, python algorithms perform better with recursion rather than iteration.

Comment: Interesting... Can you give some example code to back this up? Sorting is a bit convoluted I suppose.